# Thread.sleep method start before everything

Tags: android

I have an array of few balls, and i want at first, to draw each 1 after about half a second, so im drawing the ball and after the draw method im using Thread.sleep, but when i run the application it just sleep and then its drawing all of the balls. Any Idea Why?

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) 
    {
        this.arr[i].draw(canvas, p);
        if(this.count < this.arr.length)
        {
            this.count++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this being called on the main thread?  If so, its drawing everything at once because you're holding up the thread.  The screen doesn't draw until it returns to the looper.  If you want to draw on a delay, implement an animation or use a timer to redraw every 500 ms.

Comment: could you give me an example on how to do it with a timer, i havent tried it so i dont know how its working.
Thanks

Comment: please insert details of code.